# Get Image src with specific class in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have the following code, where I store all src in an array, I would like to store only img with class name xyz

```
const imgs = await page.$$eval('img[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
```

I tried to user filter, but I couldn't reach the right syntax to do that.

Answer (score 15):

Just add `.xyz` to your query string:

```
const imgs = await page.$$eval('img.xyz[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get all the SRC addresses inside of a class latest-photos:

```
<div class="latest-photos">

    <img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=0" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img1" alt="OptionalI Image 1" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
    <img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=1" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img2" alt="OptionalI Image 2" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
    <img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=2" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img3" alt="Option
    
    alI Image 3" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
</div>
```

You use:

```
const imgs = await page.$$eval('.latest-photos img[src]', imgs => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute('src')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
    const imgaes = await page.$$eval('img', anchors => [].map.call(anchors, img => img.src));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
async function scrapeProduct(url){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);

const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/span');
const src = await el.getProperty('src');
const image = await src.jsonValue();

console.log({image});

browser.close();

}

    scrapeProduct('https://soundcloud.com/sudo_normi_music/shibuya-drift');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want dynamic attribute

```
<div class="latest-photos">
<img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=0" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img1" alt="OptionalI Image 1" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
<img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=1" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img2" alt="OptionalI Image 2" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
<img src="/LogoImage.ashx?sn=14376&imgNbr=2" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMiddle_cphCenterColumn_uctDiveInfoDisplay_img3" alt="Option alI Image 3" width="170" style="vertical-align: top;" />
</div>


const attr = "src";
const imgs = await page.$$eval('.latest-photos img[src]', (imgs, value) => imgs.map(img => img.getAttribute(value)), attr);
```